# Configuração virtualhost

Tags: regex, redirecionamento, redirecionamento-de-url, virtualhost

Estou com uma dúvida na configuração do **`VirtualHost`**, tenho uma aplicação que tem redirecionamento para vários núcleos ex:

- `meusite.com.br/app/go`
- `meusite.com.br/app/rj`

Quando acesso `meusite.com.br/app`, ele redireciona para o primeiro núcleo da lista que está configurada em um arquivo `.xhtml`, portanto de qualquer lugar do país sempre redireciona para o `AC`.

Preciso criar uma configuração, que quando o usuário acesse `/app`, vá para uma página para que ele possa selecionar o núcleo que deseja acessar, no caso seria `/escolherestado`.

Preciso que o redirecionamento `/app` continue existindo pois toda a aplicação depende desse redirecionamento, mais preciso que sempre que o pessoal acessar `meusite.com.br/app` ou `/app/` seja redirecionado para `/escolherestado` sem que `/app/[sigla_nucleo]`" seja afetado.

Answer (score 0):

Para capturar os padrões que você quer, pode usar essa regex:

```
(meusite\.com\.br\/app)(\/{0,1})(?!.{1})
```

E usar um grupo de substituição como esse:

```
$1\/escolherestado
```

> Você pode conferir o funcionamento dessa regex [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/8X64Wp/1).

**Explicação**

```
(meusite\.com\.br\/app)
```

A regex acima captura a cadeia de caracteres **meusite.com.br/app** no grupo de captura 1 (o primeiro parenteses).

```
(\/{0,1})
```

Essa parte define que pode haver `/`no final da cadeia. 
Está cercado por outros parenteses, pois a substituição será somente com o grupo de captura 1

```
(?!.{1})
```

O final é um *negative lookahead*, ele define que não deve ser capturada a cadeia se houver algum caractere que não seja quebra de linha no final da captura, logo não capturará `/app/[sigla_nucleo]`

Após isso deve ser usado um grupo de substituição para o grupo 1, para acrescentar o final.
Logo deve ser usado `$1` (grupo 1 capturado sem a barra no final: vulgo **meusite.com.br/app**) e se adiciona `/escolherestado`.

```
$1\/escolherestado
```

Formando **meusite.com.br/app/escolherestado**